# How to use static methods in c#

Tags: c#, static

Why do the following codes return `1,1,1` instead of `1,2,3`? I'd like to keep the `int temp`value so that I can use it somewhere else. And It works if I call `Console.WriteLine(count())` directly.

```
class Program
{
    private static int start = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int temp = count();
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
        temp = count();
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
        temp = count();
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }

    static int count()
    {
        return start + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking... what didn't work about it? what is the expected behavior? "did not work" doesn't really explain much

Comment: These are really very basic things. You have them explained all around the internet, including the MSDN documentation. Please explain what do you expect (what do you mean by "not working"), referring to these sources to indicate which part in particular is confusing to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ndech's code will perform the desired output from your (modified) question, the reason you're seeing 1,1,1 each time is due to:

```
static int count()
{
    return start + 1;
}
```

When start = 0, if you return start + 1 each time you call count(), then each time it's going to be 0+1.  the code example provided by Ndech will do:

```
start = 0; // before first console.write
count();
start = 1; // first console.write
count();
start = 2;
etc...
```

another way this could be written is:

```
static int count()
{
    return ++start; // take the current value of start, and add one to it.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you expect the count to return a value that increments at each call, you should store the modified value back in the variable :

```
static int count()
{
    start = start + 1;
    return start;
}
```